# Jfreechart XYPlot, how can i draw a legend into the Plot-Area?

Tags: java, swing, charts, plot, jfreechart

i'm drawing several charts with XY-Plots in my application.
I have no problem displaying a legend under (or on top, left or right of)
the plot.

But to save space i want to draw a legend-box into the XY-Plot.

I'm able to draw image-,text- and line-annotations into the plot.

So i tried to make a TitleAnnotation from my LegendTitle and add this
annotation to the plot.

```
    LegendTitle legend = new LegendTitle(plot.getRenderer());
    XYTitleAnnotation anno = new XYTitleAnnotation(20.0, 40.0, legend);
    plot.addAnnotation(anno);
```

The coordinates of the annotation(20.0, 40.0) are in the visible area of the plot,
but nothing is drawn.

If i let the Chart-Object draw the legend under the plot this is done fine
(but not what i need).

```
    chart.addLegend(legend);
```

So i think the LegendTitle object is correct. But why is it not drawn as Annotation?

I hope someone can figure this out or help me with a different way to draw a legend into the plotarea.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be inside an `XYPlot`, I think you need an [`XYTextAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYTextAnnotation.html).

Comment: I never noticed the [variety](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYAnnotation.html) before!

Comment: Thanks, i'm able to do text Annotations but i want a complete legend with markers and Text.

Comment: In worst case i'll try to build my own legend with shape and text annotations. Or is there a way to overlay a other Swing panel over a chart panel?

Comment: I don't know. What [layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797012/jfreechart-series-tool-tip-above-shape-annotation) are you using for your `XYTitleAnnotation`?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apetresc/JFreeChart

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html

http://kickjava.com/src/org/jfree/chart/DefaultOldLegend.java.htm

Comment: Thanks, but none of your links can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: +1 [`addAnnotation()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#addAnnotation%28org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYAnnotation,%20boolean%29) looks promising.