# What open-source java charting library can mark domains in a category bar chart?

Tags: java, charts, plot, jfreechart

I'm plotting my data in a bar chart and would like to draw vertical lines between particular bars to segment the plot into domains:

[Example](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/7072/examplechart.png)

I haven't been able to find a library that can do this. jfreechart has so called domain markers but draws them through the middle of the bars, so you're really marking individual bars instead of domains:

[Example](http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/2241/screenshot20110919at182.png)

Does anyone know a library that can do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JFreechart`](http://www.jfree.org/) includes a number of `Marker` subclasses that are pictured among the `Miscellaneous > Markers` section of the [samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html). In addition, many plots allow customizing the gridline and/or crosshair `Stroke`. For arbitrary lines and shapes, consider one of the [`org.jfree.chart.annotations`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html), such as `XYLineAnnotation`, demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797012/jfreechart-series-tool-tip-above-shape-annotation/6802375#6802375).