# How to set attribute in image map using JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

How can I set an attribute of an image map using JFreeChart in servlet?

**Example:**

```
<map id="imageMap" name="imageMap">
<area shape="rect" coords="98,200,155,328" title="(Section, First Section) = 9" alt="" href="index.html?series=Section&amp;category=First+Section"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="50,301,674,643" title=" axisType='XAXIS' " alt=""/>
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,342" title=" axisType='YAXIS' " alt=""/>
</map>
```

I want to set the **id** or the **class** attribute for each area tag for it to look like this:

```
<map id="imageMap" name="imageMap" class="sectionImageMap">
<area id="sec_1" class= "section" shape="rect" coords="98,200,155,328" title="(Section, First Section) = 9" alt="" href="javascript:getReports('this')"/>
<area id="sec_2" class= "section" shape="rect" coords="50,301,674,643" title=" axisType='XAXIS' " alt="" href="javascript:getReports('this')"/>
<area id="sec_3" class= "section" shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,342" title=" axisType='YAXIS' " alt="" href="javascript:getReports('this')"/>
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYAnnotation.html); several are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797012/jfreechart-series-tool-tip-above-shape-annotation/6802375#6802375) and in the [samples/demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).