# Jfreechart annotations disappearing

Tags: java, annotations, jfreechart

I plot a curve with JFreechart. Then the user can draw ranges by dragging the mouse. These I plot using AbstractChartAnnotation to draw a filled Path2D. So far so nice - all aligns perfectly with the curve.

When an area was already annotated the new annotation gets deleted. I use `XYPlot.removeAnnotation` with the new annotation.

My problem is that sometimes not only the "new" annotation gets removed, but also a second annotation elsewhere in the plot. It doesn't seem random - I kinda found annotations to the "right" side more prone to this happening.

I'm very confused what could cause this. The object that draws/deletes the new annotation is reinstated every time and only holds the current annotation - so how could the other annotation be deleted?

Would be very grateful for any hints, thanks.

---

As suggested I prepare a sscce example. Unfortunately it's not too short.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.annotations.AbstractXYAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.Plot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.Millisecond;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesDataItem;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge;

/**
 *
 * @author c.ager
 */
public class IntegrationSSCE {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jFrame.setSize(600, 400);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(jFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TimeSeriesCollection timeSeriesCollection = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        TimeSeries timeSeries = new TimeSeries("test");
        for (long i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            double val = Math.random() + 3 * Math.exp(-Math.pow(i - 300, 2) / 1000);
            timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(i)), val);
        }
        timeSeriesCollection.addSeries(timeSeries);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                null,
                null, "data", timeSeriesCollection,
                true, true, false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.removeMouseListener(chartPanel);

        Set<MyAnnot> annotSet = new TreeSet<MyAnnot>();

        AnnotListener list = new AnnotListener(chartPanel, annotSet, timeSeries);
        chartPanel.addMouseListener(list);
        chartPanel.addMouseMotionListener(list);

        jFrame.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    private static class AnnotListener implements MouseInputListener {

        Point2D start, end;
        MyAnnot currAnnot;
        final Set<MyAnnot> annotSet;
        final ChartPanel myChart;
        final TimeSeries timeSeries;

        public AnnotListener(ChartPanel myChart, Set<MyAnnot> annotSet, TimeSeries timeSeries) {
            this.myChart = myChart;
            this.annotSet = annotSet;
            this.timeSeries = timeSeries;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            start = convertScreePoint2DataPoint(e.getPoint());
            currAnnot = new MyAnnot(start, timeSeries, myChart.getChart().getXYPlot());
            myChart.getChart().getXYPlot().addAnnotation(currAnnot);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            end = convertScreePoint2DataPoint(e.getPoint());
            currAnnot.updateEnd(end);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            boolean test = annotSet.add(currAnnot);
            if (!test) {
                myChart.getChart().getXYPlot().removeAnnotation(currAnnot);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        protected Point2D convertScreePoint2DataPoint(Point in) {
            Rectangle2D plotArea = myChart.getScreenDataArea();
            XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) myChart.getChart().getPlot();
            double x = plot.getDomainAxis().java2DToValue(in.getX(), plotArea, plot.getDomainAxisEdge());
            double y = plot.getRangeAxis().java2DToValue(in.getY(), plotArea, plot.getRangeAxisEdge());
            return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        }
    }

    private static class MyAnnot extends AbstractXYAnnotation implements Comparable<MyAnnot> {

        Long max;
        Line2D line;
        final TimeSeries timeSeries;
        final XYPlot plot;
        final Stroke stroke  = new BasicStroke(1.5f);

        public MyAnnot(Point2D start, TimeSeries timeSeries, XYPlot plot) {
            this.plot = plot;
            this.timeSeries = timeSeries;

            line = new Line2D.Double(start, start);
            findMax();
        }

        public void updateEnd(Point2D end) {
            line.setLine(line.getP1(), end);
            findMax();
            fireAnnotationChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D gd, XYPlot xyplot, Rectangle2D rd, ValueAxis va, ValueAxis va1, int i, PlotRenderingInfo pri) {
            PlotOrientation orientation = plot.getOrientation();
            RectangleEdge domainEdge = Plot.resolveDomainAxisLocation(
                    plot.getDomainAxisLocation(), orientation);
            RectangleEdge rangeEdge = Plot.resolveRangeAxisLocation(
                    plot.getRangeAxisLocation(), orientation);

            double m02 = va.valueToJava2D(0, rd, domainEdge);
            // y-axis translation
            double m12 = va1.valueToJava2D(0, rd, rangeEdge);
            // x-axis scale
            double m00 = va.valueToJava2D(1, rd, domainEdge) - m02;
            // y-axis scale
            double m11 = va1.valueToJava2D(1, rd, rangeEdge) - m12;

            Shape s = null;
            if (orientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                AffineTransform t1 = new AffineTransform(
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                AffineTransform t2 = new AffineTransform(
                        m11, 0.0f, 0.0f, m00, m12, m02);
                s = t1.createTransformedShape(line);
                s = t2.createTransformedShape(s);
            } else if (orientation == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
                AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform(m00, 0, 0, m11, m02, m12);
                s = t.createTransformedShape(line);
            }
            gd.setStroke(stroke);
            gd.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            gd.draw(s);
            addEntity(pri, s.getBounds2D(), i, getToolTipText(), getURL());
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyAnnot o) {
            return max.compareTo(o.max);
        }

        private void findMax() {
            max = (long) line.getP1().getX();

            Point2D left, right;
            if (line.getP1().getX() < line.getP2().getX()) {
                left = line.getP1();
                right = line.getP2();
            } else {
                left = line.getP2();
                right = line.getP1();
            }
            Double maxVal = left.getY();
            List<TimeSeriesDataItem> items = timeSeries.getItems();
            for (Iterator<TimeSeriesDataItem> it = items.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                TimeSeriesDataItem dataItem = it.next();
                if (dataItem.getPeriod().getFirstMillisecond() < left.getX()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (dataItem.getPeriod().getFirstMillisecond() > right.getX()) {
                    break;
                }
                double curVal = dataItem.getValue().doubleValue();
                if (curVal > maxVal) {
                    maxVal = curVal;
                    max = dataItem.getPeriod().getFirstMillisecond();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problematic behaviour. Note that images 2 and 4 were taken while the mouse button was pressed.

1. select a few non-overlapping lines - no problem as it should be
   [image: select a few non-overlapping lines]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

---

I have just been looking at it in the debugger - could it be that ArrayList.remove(Object o) removes the WRONG element? Seems very unlikely to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at the [`Layer`](http://jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/ui/Layer.html) to which the annotation is being added. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802375/230513). Naturally, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe would help clarify the source of the problem.

Addendum: One potential problem is that your implementation of [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is *not* consistent with `equals()`, as the latter relies (implicitly) on the super-class implementation. A consistent implementation is required for use with a sorted `Set` such as `TreeSet`. You'll need to override `hashCode()`, too. Class [`Value`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) is an example.

Comment: Ok created a sscce. But can't find the layer. Can you point me?

Comment: If you have access to [_Effective Java_](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), see items 9 & 12.

Comment: ah - we are getting somewhere! overriding hashCode alone didn't help - but I got a message I should also override `equals` and now I don't see the "weird" behavior in the example. Unfortunately I don't have access to the book you suggest. What do the chapters you suggest treat?

Comment: Just as note - in my application I didn't implement `Comparable` in my annotation. I was just relying that the "default" method would work. Turns out I was wrong.

Comment: I habitually & defensively override all three: `compareTo()`, `equals()` & `hashCode()`. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Seems a good advice. You nailed it on first try - thanks a lot :D