# XYChart draw text and lines

Tags: java, javafx-2

My question: I have two button (either Swing or JavaFX, no matter) new JButton("Text"); and new JButton("Line");

By selecting the "Text" button and clicking on a XYChart I would like to write my custom text via keyboard typing;

By selecting "Line" button I would like to be able to draw lines on XYChart.

How to accomplish these tasks?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example about drawing lines in a jFreeChart XYChart in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995212/jfreechart-annotations-disappearing).