# TextAnnotation is being hidden by JFreeChart plot

Tags: java, plot, annotations, jfreechart

I have been working on JFreeChart from quite amount of time. I am using `XYTextAnnotation` to label the points. For some point labels, the plot is hiding the text labels; it is not giving the exact plot fit. Can any one help me?

This is what I have added.

```
XYTextAnnotation textannotation = new XYTextAnnotation(dynamictext, x-value, y-value);
plot.add(textannotation);
```

This is what I am getting.

[image: here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JFreechart series tool tip above shape annotation*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6797012/230513) and [*Jfreechart annotations disappearing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8995212/230513). If your question is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: trashgod,this belongs to XYTextannotation am convinced that it is not duplicate - @trashgod

Comment: At a guess, your annotation `x-value` and `y-value` values are off. Your [mcve] should help clarify the matter.

Comment: exactly trashgod. the x-value and y-values are dynamic, chart isn't setting those values inside the plot. - @trashgod

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe.

Comment: thanks for trying,am trying to do it with Marker i don't know how it turns up.Nice to meet you. -@trashgod