# How can I draw a filled rectangle in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm making a little application using Swing and JFreeChart. I have to display an `XYLineChart`, and I want to draw some filled rectangles over it. I've used the `XYShapeAnnotation` to draw the rectangles, and I've tried to fill them with `Graphics2D`, but it doesn't work. I get the rectangle displayed over the chart, but not filled. The code looks like this:

```
Shape rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 7, 1);
g2.fill(rectangle);
XYShapeAnnotation shapeAnnotation = new XYShapeAnnotation(rectangle, new BasicStroke(2.f), Color.BLACK);
shapeAnnotation.setToolTipText("1");
plot.addAnnotation(shapeAnnotation);
```

I think the problem is that the filled rectangle position is not relative to the chart, but I don't really know how to fix this. I've also wanted to know if it's possible to display the lines in the chart over the rectangles, because I don't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`XYShapeAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html) constructor that allows you to specify *both* `outlinePaint` *and* `fillPaint`. You probably want something like this:

```
XYShapeAnnotation shapeAnnotation = new XYShapeAnnotation(
    rectangle, new BasicStroke(2.f), Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
```

As a concrete example based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35236100/230513), the following change produces the result shown:

```
 renderer.addAnnotation(new XYShapeAnnotation(ellipse, stroke, color, color));
```

[image: image1]

To display the lines in the chart *over* the rectangles, specify the background layer for the annotation, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802375/230513).

```
 renderer.addAnnotation(new XYShapeAnnotation(
     ellipse, stroke, color, color), Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

[image: image2]

Comment: It worked, thank you. Do you also know how to display the chart lines over the rectangles?

Comment: @novayhulk14: Glad it helped; concerning "lines over the rectangles," you may have seen a page that was cached before my [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54552387/revisions).

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly what I wanted :)