# How to set Border around value label in bar chart using Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: bar-chart, pentaho, jfreechart, pentaho-report-designer

I am using Pentaho Report Designer (PRD) and a JFreeChart `CategoryPlot`. Does anyone know how to set a border around value label? The image shows the expected output.

[image: Expected Result]

I need a border around last value of bar chart (circled) using Pentaho Report Designer or using JFreeChart.

Comment: Have you looked at a suitable one of the `org.jfree.chart.annotations`?

Comment: Hi @trashgod... i am new in pentaho report as well as jfree...can you please explain me with example?

Comment: I don't use [tag:pentaho], but annotation examples may be found in the [tag:jfreechart] [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjfreechart%5D+org.jfree.chart.annotations).

Comment: @trashgod.. Can you please explain how to use annotations in this issue??

Comment: I don't know [tag:pentaho]; an [mcve] might make it easier for someone who knows pentaho; here are more [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20annotation); what have you tried so far?

Comment: @trashgod its ok you can explain me this problem with example in Jfree... You can use Jfree chart as source code to explain this example.

Comment: @trashgod here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204012/how-to-change-the-color-of-multiple-ellipses-using-a-loop-jfreechart is example of ellipse.. but i don't know how to use it as value label border of bar chart... can you please explain me this with Jfree code Example?

Comment: Yes, `XYShapeAnnotation` is a good choice for `XYPlot`; also consider using `CategoryPointerAnnotation` for `CategoryPlot`; it's not clear which you're using; in any case, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your use case and chosen approach.

Comment: @trashgod Yes i want code using CategoryPlot...assume that i want a bar chart whose value label contain ellipse border.(same as image)...sorry to say but i am not able to share my code... as it is not in sharable.

Comment: I don't see a `Shape` annotation for `CategoryPlot`; you may be able to create a category annotation with a custom `draw()` implementation; I don't have an example, but you might look at the existing source and [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/search.php?keywords=extends+AbstractAnnotation).

Comment: @trashgod i am new in Jfree i am not able to get without example...please help me it means a lot to me,.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand; I've cited numerous examples.