# Layering annotations for JFreeChart

Tags: java, user-interface, annotations, jfreechart

Im trying to layer annotations on my `JFreeChart`. Currently the annotations appear above my graph, but I want them to appear bellow the point.

```
xyPlot.addAnnotation(MECamVisArea, Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

When I enter this line, I get an error message that says incompatible type layer can't be converted to `Boolean`. I'll leave my full annotation code bellow.

```
XYPolygonAnnotation MECamVisArea = new XYPolygonAnnotation(new double[]{0.0, 0.0,
    defaultPosX, (defaultPosX*tan(0.907571)), defaultPosX, -(defaultPosX*tan(0.907571))}) {

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2, XYPlot plot, Rectangle2D dataArea, ValueAxis
        domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis, int rendererIndex, PlotRenderingInfo info) {
    Graphics2D g22 = (Graphics2D) g2.create();
    g22.setXORMode(new Color(0xff3300));
    super.draw(g22, plot, dataArea, domainAxis, rangeAxis, rendererIndex, info);
    }
};

xyPlot.addAnnotation(MECamVisArea, Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802375/230513), you are adding your [`XYPolygonAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYPolygonAnnotation.html) to an [`XYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html), which offers an [`addAnnotation()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#addAnnotation-org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYAnnotation-boolean-) method that expects a `boolean` parameter. Instead, add the annotation to your chosen [`XYItemRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYItemRenderer.html), which offer an [`addAnnotation()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYItemRenderer.html#addAnnotation-org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYAnnotation-org.jfree.ui.Layer-) method that expects an `org.jfree.ui.Layer` parameter.