# Place a circle on top of an XYLineChart in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I've drawn a standard normal distribution using JFreeChart:

```
NormalDistributionFunction2D normalDistributionFunction2D = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(0.5, 0.15);
XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normalDistributionFunction2D, 0.0, 1.0, 1000, "Normal");
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("MyTitle --, "", "", xySeriesCollection, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
```

[image: Standard normal distribution]

On top of this, I would like to place a circle at a given point. I have no problems with calculating the [x,y] co-ordinates of the circle, but I am unsure as to how I can add it to the chart. Any help appreciated. An MS Paint knockup of what I want to achieve is below.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You absolutely do not need to override the paint method or add a layer on top. JFreeChart already has support for this behavior.

The correct way is to add annotations to the chart, specifically:

```
chart.getPlot().addAnnotation(new XYShapeAnnotation(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - radius, y - radius, radius + radius, radius + radius))
```

where x and y is the center of the circle. Note, the coordinates are in your plot space, not the graphical space. JFreeChart will automatically transform them when rendering.

Take a look at:
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartPlotOrientationDemo2.htm

Comment: See also related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620017/230513).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the point's coordinates, you can:

1. Add your chart to a JPanel and draw the circle on its `paintComponent`(a bit difficult as you have to compensate for the chart borders
2. Draw a second series on the same chart that contains only one point. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665354/changing-the-shapes-of-points-in-scatter-plot/6669529#6669529) for defining custom shapes to render the data point - you can define a circle to be rendered as your data point

Comment: How do you access the chart's paintComponent method since it is created by a factory and thus cannot be extended?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels True, the chart should be add to a JPanel instead

Comment: Annotations are designed for this, but a second series is a useful alternative; overriding `paintComponent()` is a bad idea, as it can;t easily access the renderer's geometry.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is add a point with x and y coordinates say (0,0) to a series. Now, set `renderer.setSeriesShape(series,new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 6, 6));` now you can update the series and make point moveable aswell.