# Change colour & line width of an Annotation in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am adding an annotation to my plot, but I can't work out how to change the colour or line width (stroke) of this. I've read through the documentation as best as I can but I'm out of ideas. Can anyone help?

```
Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(circleXValue - radius, circleYValue - radius, radius + radius, radius + radius);
XYShapeAnnotation annotation = new XYShapeAnnotation(shape);
// ??
plot.addAnnotation(annotation);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using this [constructor](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html#XYShapeAnnotation%28java.awt.Shape%29):

```
public XYShapeAnnotation(java.awt.Shape shape)
```

You may want to use one of [these constructors](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html#XYShapeAnnotation%28java.awt.Shape,%20java.awt.Stroke,%20java.awt.Paint%29) that specify additional parameters:

```
public XYShapeAnnotation(
    java.awt.Shape shape,
    java.awt.Stroke stroke,
    java.awt.Paint outlinePaint)

public XYShapeAnnotation(
    java.awt.Shape shape,
    java.awt.Stroke stroke,
    java.awt.Paint outlinePaint,
    java.awt.Paint fillPaint)
```

Comment: Edited to cite the API; the source is not needed for this. Please don't copy LGPL code fragments here; this site uses a different [license](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: Thanks trashgod - I'm a newbie around here so might take me a while to get up to speed with the rite way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

You can find related examples using [`XYShapeAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html#XYShapeAnnotation%28java.awt.Shape,%20java.awt.Stroke,%20java.awt.Paint%29) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620017/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513).

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]