# How to generate smooth curved graph using JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am generating line chart using jfree chart, but I am able to generate a line chart which is not looking so good. I want to generate an image like the following

[image]

Can anybody please suggest any solution?

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a line chart, you will have to change the renderer you use to `XYSplineRenderer`. See the javadocs for this [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYSplineRenderer.html).

Answer (score 1):

[`ArcTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620017/230513) shows how to use an [`XYShapeAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html) that can be any [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) at all.